# Update rows from select which return us table

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, select

i have problem with updating rows. I have row "count" in one table and reference to another table "population_id", and want to update this row "count" using select which return us table with values (count(client_id), population_id)
There exist way to do this, and what the simplest way?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION zonning.set_count_population(label text)
RETURNS void AS
$BODY$declare
BEGIN
UPDATE zonning.populations2 SET count = 
(SELECT  count(c.client_id)
FROM    clients.clients c
JOIN clients.phone_numbers pn ON c.client_id = pn.client_id
JOIN clients.phone_numbers_labels pnl ON pn.phone_number_id = pnl.phone_number_id
JOIN clients.labels l ON pnl.label_id = l.label_id
WHERE l.label_name = label)
WHERE population_id = "How i can get id from select?";
END;$BODY$ `
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE 
COST 100;
```

Comment: `How i can get id from select?` ... which value are you referring to?

Comment: How are you updating this in the UI I mean passing QueryString or anything else?

Comment: In this case, select is used as a scalar subquery (in fact a *very* tiny table, hopefully exactly one value) BTW `count` is a bad choice for a column name, since it is a keyword. BTW2: `"How i can get id from select?"` : string literals should be quoted with single quotes, double quotes are for identifiers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PostgreSQL, you can have a `FROM` clause in an `UPDATE` statement to join with other tables, like this:

```
UPDATE populations2 pn
SET count = (subselect using "pn" and "ot")
FROM other_table ot
WHERE pn.population_id = ot.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not MySQL expert, but I think it should be possible to do like this:

```
UPDATE zonning.populations2 SET count = 
(SELECT  count(c.client_id)
FROM    clients.clients c
JOIN clients.phone_numbers pn ON c.client_id = pn.client_id
JOIN clients.phone_numbers_labels pnl ON pn.phone_number_id = pnl.phone_number_id
JOIN clients.labels l ON pnl.label_id = l.label_id
WHERE l.label_name = zonning.populations2.label)
WHERE population_id = "How i can get id from select?";
```

Here's simplified example:

**<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/707ee/1)</kbd>**